# Querying MySQL Timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm querying the timestamp from the field `created` in the table `messages`.
My database table currently stands as..

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| msg_id |  messages | uid_fk | ip |   created   | uploads |
| 706    |  ........ |   39   | .. |  1368631445 |    0    |
| 717    |  ........ |   39   | .. |  1368640802 |    0    |
| 705    |  ........ |   39   | .. |  1368631238 |    0    |
| 696    |  ........ |   39   | .. |  1368595705 |    0    |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This is how I'm querying the timestamp from `created`.

```
public function Time_Stamp($uid){
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT created FROM messages WHERE uid_fk='$uid'");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ) {
        echo date("g:i", strtotime($row["created"])) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

----- Output -----

1. 9:00
2. 9:00
3. 9:00
4. 9:00
   So basically just printing out in a list the same time.

It's not printing their unique time from the `created` field. I'm not so perfect with MySQL but It has do to with their unique iD's(either msg_id, uid_fk) also, $uid equals the uid_fk, $uid is defined in another table.

How do I go about bringing their specific iD's to print out their correct timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date("g:i", $row["created"]);
```

`strtotime` turns a *date string* like `2013-05-15 22:35:00` into a *timestamp*.
`date` turns a *timestamp* into a readable *date string*.
You already have timestamps in the database, don't use `strtotime`.

Comment: Sigh, so simple I appreciate it!
What is a good way to use strtotime? Or where would be most correct place to use it?

Comment: There are two (commonly used) possible date representations: numeric timestamps and standardized formats like "2013-05-15 22:35:00". It's easy to do math on numeric timestamps and it's easier to read date strings. Use `date` and `strtotime` accordingly to turn one into the other as needed.

Comment: Great, now I understand it! Thank you for the help.